# How to replicate auto increment Primary Key In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this model class:
**Item:**

```
public ITEM_ID { internal get; set; }
public int ITEM_CODE { get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

The `ITEM_ID` is the primary key and its auto_increment.
What I want to do is that when I click on the Save button, the value of the primary key (`ITEM_ID`) which is auto generated, should be replicated and also saved in `ITEM_CODE`

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(ITEM item)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _itemService.AddItem(item);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "We cannot add this Item. Verify your data entries !");
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

Comment: What database technology are you using? MVC is a presentation pattern, it has nothing to do with primary keys, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set id manually in c# code.
I mean like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    item.ITEM_ID = SetItemID();
    _itemService.AddItem(item);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private int SetItemID()
{
    //Get the latest ID from database
    return lastId + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Please sorry if my question is silly. The system is saying that **lastId** is unknown. How do I resolve this

Comment: You should define and set lastId in comment area. It based on your defines. For example if you define with dbml you sohuld define dataccontext and query should look like this;
 using (DataContextProvider dcp = new DataContextProvider())
{
Repository<Table> rep = new Repository<Table>(dcp);
                rep.GetAll().First().OrderByDescending(t=>t.ID);//you should use Top linq query in here it is just an example
but it changes in every project so you should use your own connectionstrings ...etc.